# Apply Stereotype to operation in Eclipse UML-Designer

Tags: eclipse, uml-designer

[Applying a stereotype to an operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMYvh.png)

Hi, in the image I have a "REST" stereotype that I would like to apply to the "Operation_2". In effect, at a system level, I want to say that this is a REST API.

I have tried Melanie's suggestion (thank you), but my REST stereotype does not seem to appear as an option.

[Stereotype in profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGcl0.png)

I have also tried creating a profile, and putting the REST stereotype in the profile. Then tried by selecting the stereotype option from the context/symbol menu that appears when the cursor is over the operation in the class diagram. That is illustrated above, but no luck there either.

Many thanks

Nathan

Comment: Same problem here. No way to see the stereotype applicable for a property...

Answer (score -1):

There is many different ways to apply a stereotype on an operation. The easiest one is to activate the Stereotype layer. 
[image: Activate the Stereotype Layer]

This will add a new Stereotype tool in the palette. Then select this tool and click on your operation, it opens a dialog to select a stereotype.

[image: Use the stereotype tool]

You will see the stereotype appplied on your operation.

[image: Operation with an applied stereotype]